# ptrace abnormal values returned in the registers

Tags: c++, ptrace

I've got an assignment and i have to use ptrace to trace the system calls of an application.
The problem is that when i am running the program it gives me some uncommon values, that i obtain from the registers, as output. Some of those values are negative numbers.

Here is the code: http://pastebin.com/iMXYmqG6
And here is some sample output: http://pastebin.com/bVa5vnWT

If anyone could give me some directions on what i am doing wrong i would be really grateful.

P.S. I am working on a 64-bit OS but i am building a 32 bit application(that was a restriction for the assignment.)

Comment: Probably the random huge numbers are because the call needs less than three parameters, and the ones it does not need are ignored.

Comment: Well i haven't checked all the calls but at least the open,read and write calls need 3 parameters based on this site http://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/linuxsyscalls/ and those calls return some huge negative numbers aswell.

Comment: erm i think i know why i get those strange values, its probably because i am trying to debug a 64 bit application with a 32 bit debugger. Could that be the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using 64 bit os you have to use registers used in 64 bit compatible. i.e., RAX,ORIG_EAX,EBX,EBX.....If not you will get garbage values